# Xcode Mac: Animate Object Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am making a game where you are an image moving through a maze. I do the animations with a few methods I have created myself:

**My way**
*From my own class 'SCGF'*

```
+ (void)moveObject:(NSImageView *)image x:(float)x y:(float)y
{
    NSRect newFrame;

    newFrame.origin.x = x;
    newFrame.origin.y = y;
    newFrame.size.height = image.frame.size.height;
    newFrame.size.width  = image.frame.size.width;

    [image setFrame:newFrame];
}

+ (void)moveObject:(NSImageView *)image sX:(float)sX eX:(float)eX sY:(float)sY eY:(float)eY inSteps:(int)steps
{
    [SCGF moveObject:image x:sX y:sY];

    for(int i = 1; i <= steps; i++)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 * i repeats:NO block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
                 if(sX >= eX && sY >= eY) [self moveObject:image x:image.frame.origin.x - ((sX - eX) / steps) y:image.frame.origin.y - ((sY - eY) / steps)];
            else if(sX >= eX && sY <= eY) [self moveObject:image x:image.frame.origin.x - ((sX - eX) / steps) y:image.frame.origin.y + ((eY - sY) / steps)];
            else if(sX <= eX && sY >= eY) [self moveObject:image x:image.frame.origin.x + ((eX - sX) / steps) y:image.frame.origin.y - ((sY - eY) / steps)];
            else if(sX <= eX && sY <= eY) [self moveObject:image x:image.frame.origin.x + ((eX - sX) / steps) y:image.frame.origin.y + ((eY - sY) / steps)];
        }] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 * steps repeats:NO block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer)     {
        // Makes sure it is in its end position
        [SCGF moveObject:image x:eX y:eY];
    }] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

**The problem**

This works very well if you only have one object that you want to move across the screen. If you want to do two or more simultaneous animations this will get very slow. Also, when you start a new animation, the other already running animations will stop for a short time. This probably has something to do with all the NSTimers running every 0.01 seconds.

**Other ways of doing it**

I heard that there already is a way to moving an image across the screen. Something like this in iOS:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var destinationY:CGFloat = self.view.bounds.height / 2 // Your destination Y
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.3, options: nil, animations: {
        self.imageView.center.y = destinationY
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

*Code snippet from [best simplest code to move a UIImage View from point A to point B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066602/best-simplest-code-to-move-a-uiimage-view-from-point-a-to-point-b)*

This code is written in Swift and is written for iOS. My application is written in Objective-C and it's a game for Mac (OS X).

**To the point**

I have searched for tutorials on how to do this on the internet. Most of the tutorials are for iOS apps in Swift. I'd like to know how you'd do this for Mac Apps in Objective-C. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Google for CoreAnimation and NSView together, that should give you more Mac results.

You should be able to just do `myView.animator.frame = newFrame;` to cause a view to smoothly fly from one spot to the other. To control the speed or make sure that several views animate together from the same start time, wrap them in `[CATransaction begin]`/`[CATransaction commit]`, then call other `CATransaction` methods.

You may also want to turn on layer-backed drawing for those views that are moved a lot. That will move the drawing from the CPU onto the graphics card, making it a lot faster.

But note that layer-backed views get implicit animations (most notably they will fade in/out when hidden/shown), which you may want to inhibit using `CATransaction` and/or overriding `-animationForKey:@"subviews"` to return `[NSNull null]` for your view.

*Note:* NSViews are not really intended for games. They are intended for user interfaces, and usually you don't want too many of them moving quickly and overlapping.

For a game where many things move and animate, a better choice would probably be to use SpriteKit.